# config file in android kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, nexus-7, android-kernel

I have downloaded tegra kernel source for Nexus 7 (grouper).
I have added a driver module in drivers/bluetooth/

I have updated the make file and Kconfig file in drivers/bluetooth/

Added the following flags to tegra3_android_defconfig

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_BT_MYMODULE=m
```

But when i issue the command

```
make tegra3_android_defconfig
```

I find CONFIG_BT_MYMODULE=y in .config file.
Note: The driver module which i have developed does not have dependency on any other kernel modules.

Comment: Is there another tegra3_android_defconfig in your build tree?  Are the other config lines intact after you do a build?  IIRC, the Android build environment will copy the config file from another location in the tree and overwrite another config file.

Comment: I have verified that tegra3_android_defconfig is correct config file. When CONFIG_BT_MYMODULE=n in tegra3_android_defconfig, no flag is seen in .config file. This confirms that only tegra3_android_defconfig is used for the build and .config file is generated.

Comment: Is CONFIG_MODULES or the config for enabling module loading set in the kernel?

Comment: This issue got resolved. There was an entry in tegra3_android_defconfig as CONFIG_MODULES=n. It was somewhere in the middle of the file. I had missed it. Thanks Peter for pointing that out.